# Javascript is not working on WordPress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

This code is not functioning the way it is on JsFiddle. It barely shows half of the app when implemented on WordPress.

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/od6g095L/

**How it's supposed to display:**

[image]

**This is how it displays on WordPress:**
[image]

This is exactly what I have on my wordpress page:

```
 <div id="container">
      <div id="content">
     <strong>What Type of Person Are You?</strong>
       <strong><h3 id="question"></h3></strong> 
        <div id="choices"></div>
        <p id="score"></p>
      </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var quiz = [{
          "question": "What is the full form of IP?",
          "choices": ["Internet Provider", "Internet Port", "Internet Protocol" , "Other"],
          "correct": "Other"
        }, {
          "question": "Who is the founder of Microsoft?",
          "choices": ["Bill Gates", "Steve Jobs", "Steve Wozniak" , "Martin Shaba"],
          "correct": "Bill Gates"
        }, {
          "question": "What was your first dream?",
          "choices": ["8 bits", "64 bits", "1024 bits"],
          "correct": "8 bits"
        }, {
          "question": "The C programming language was developed by?",
          "choices": ["Brendan Eich", "Dennis Ritchie", "Guido van Rossum"],
          "correct": "Dennis Ritchie"
        }, {
          "question": "What does CC mean in emails?",
          "choices": ["Carbon Copy", "Creative Commons", "other"],
          "correct": "Carbon Copy"
        }];


// define elements
var content = $("content"),
questionContainer = $("question"),
choicesContainer = $("choices"),
scoreContainer = $("score"),
submitBtn = $("submit");

// init vars
var currentQuestion = 0,
score = 0,
askingQuestion = true;

function $(id) { // shortcut for document.getElementById
  return document.getElementById(id);
}

function askQuestion() {
  var choices = quiz[currentQuestion].choices,
  choicesHtml = "";

  // loop through choices, and create radio buttons
  for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
    choicesHtml += "<input type='radio' name='quiz" + currentQuestion +
    "' id='choice" + (i + 1) +
    "' value='" + choices[i] + "'>" +
    " <label for='choice" + (i + 1) + "'>" + choices[i] + "</label><br>";
  }

  // load the question
  questionContainer.textContent = quiz[currentQuestion].question;

  // load the choices
  choicesContainer.innerHTML = choicesHtml;

  // setup for the first time
  if (currentQuestion === 0) {
    scoreContainer.textContent = "0 correct out of " +
    quiz.length + "";
   // submitBtn.textContent = "Submit Answer";
  }

  var radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]');
  [].forEach.call(radios, function(radio) {
    radio.onchange = function() {
      checkAnswer();
    }
  })   
}

function checkAnswer() {
  // are we asking a question, or proceeding to next question?
  if (askingQuestion) {
   // submitBtn.textContent = "Next Question";
    askingQuestion = false;

    // determine which radio button they clicked
    var userpick,
    correctIndex,
    radios = document.getElementsByName("quiz" + currentQuestion);
    for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
      if (radios[i].checked) { // if this radio button is checked
        userpick = radios[i].value;
      }

      // get index of correct answer
      if (radios[i].value == quiz[currentQuestion].correct) {
        correctIndex = i;
      }
    }

    // setup if they got it right, or wrong

    if (userpick == quiz[currentQuestion].correct) {
      score++;
    } else {
    }

    scoreContainer.textContent = "" + score + " correct out of " +
    quiz.length + "";


    askingQuestion = true;
    // change button text back to "Submit Answer"
    //submitBtn.textContent = "Submit Answer";
    // if we're not on last question, increase question number
    if (currentQuestion < quiz.length - 1) {
      currentQuestion++;
      askQuestion();
    } else {
      showFinalResults();
    }
  } else { 
  }
}

function showFinalResults() {
  content.innerHTML = "<h1>You did amazing!</h1>" +
  "<h5>Below are your results</h5>" +
  "<h2>" + score + " out of " + quiz.length + " questions, " +
  Math.round(score / quiz.length * 100) + "%<h2>";
}

window.addEventListener("load", askQuestion, false);
submitBtn.addEventListener("click", checkAnswer, false);
</script>

<style>
#container {
  max-width:600px;
  height: auto;
  background: #59C1DA;
  border: 10px solid #333;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

#content {
  border: 10px solid #fff;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #fff;

}
#question {
  font-weight: bold;
}
#score {
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure jQuery runs by default in WordPress and if so, your function `function $(id) { // shortcut for document.getElementById` will mess with jQuery's ... or the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

On jsfiddle you have the script separate. On your WordPress page it's all in an inline `<script>` tag. That means the `window.load` event has ***already occurred** by the time your script executes. You need to either just call the `askQuestion()` function directly, or (much, much, much better) put the script in a separate .js file and include it with `wp_enqueue_script()`.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by installing a WordPress plugin called "Scripts n Styles" which allows you to implement Javascript code and CSS into each post separately without it being corrupted! The html will stay in the wordpress html post.

It worked for me!!! I'm glad I solved it!!!